# Using an "if" statement in a timer performs the task without meeting the specified condition?

Tags: java, if-statement, timer

I've been having troubles with using an "if" statement in a timer. I have the timer set to run an if loop every second or so, but the action within the if statement executes even if the "if" conditions were not met. Am I doing something wrong here, or is this impossible?

Code:

```
    //GLOBAL TIMERS
    //car edge detection
    int initialDelay = 0; // start after 0 seconds
    int period = 50;        // repeat every 5 seconds
    final Timer carAI = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
      public void run() {
          if (redcar.getX() == -50); {
              redcar.setIcon(new ImageIcon(gui.class.getResource("/main/redcar.png")));
              redcar.setLocation(redcar.getX() + 5, redcar.getY());
          }

      }
    };
    carAI.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, initialDelay, period);
```

Comment: You should carefully check whether you've done anything silly with semicolons...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth 

`if (redcar.getX() == -50) {`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If @Oli's hint isnt enough, let me rewrite it as the compiler sees your code.

```
if (redcar.getX() == -50)
{;}
 ^  // the great ;
{
     redcar.setIcon(new ImageIcon(gui.class.getResource("/main/redcar.png")));
     redcar.setLocation(redcar.getX() + 5, redcar.getY());
}
```

Remove that semicolon to fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to remember that semicolon next time.